# Split array into chunks and sum each index, then merge into another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am splitting an array into two arrays `arr1` & `arr2`. Then I want to sum the values and bind into another array like `arr3`. How can I do this?

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
var arr2 = [2,3,4,4]

var arr3 = [3,5,7,8]
```

this works fine with static arrays, but my problem is

```
var TotalOfArray = [];
var temparray = [];

for (i = 0, j = x.length; i < j; i += chunk) {

        temparray = x.slice(i, i + chunk);

        if (temparray.length == chunk) {

            console.log("before loop: "+TotalOfArray.length);

            if (TotalOfArray.length == 0) {

                for (i in temparray) {
                    TotalOfArray[i] = temparray[i];
                }

                console.log("after loop: "+TotalOfArray.length);

            } else {

                for (i in temparray) {
                    TotalOfArray[i] = TotalOfArray[i] + temparray[i];
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

As you can see, x will be the main array which I am splicing into a `temparray` array, so every time it will splice with array length 31 and than I want to do sum, chunk = 31 as of now. But it's not going into ELSE part.

Comment: are you guaranteed to have the same number of elements in arr1 and arr2?

Comment: yeah, every time it will be same

Answer (score 4):

## Equal Length Arrays:

This is just a more simple version, that assumes equal lengths from both arrays. For a solution that works with variable length arrays, read further on.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 4];

var arr3 = arr1.map(function(a, i) {
  return a + arr2[i];
});

console.log(arr3);
```

## Variable Length Arrays:

This is going to be a more robust solution regardless. But it finds the array with the most values in it, and uses that for the map. Then, if undefined values are found in the other array, it will use 0 as the other number.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 4, 5];

var sorted = [arr1, arr2].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

var arr3 = sorted[0].map(function(a, i) {
  return a + (sorted[1][i] || 0);
});

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` loop:

```js
    var arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
    var arr2 = [2,3,4,4]
    var arr3 = []
    for (i in arr1) { arr3[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i]; }

    console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me on this. it worked for me. great efforts

Answer (score 1):

If two arrays have equal length you can can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);

```js
var data1 = [1,2,3,4],
    data2 = [2,3,4,4],
    result;
result = data1.map(function(value, i){
    return value + data2[i];
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thats fine but my problem is, i am splicing the array using for loop, if you can see i have added the for loop in my question.

Comment: @GopalRohila I think solution for variable array provided by KevBot should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
var arr2 = [2,3,4,4]
var arr3 = []

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr3.push(arr1[i] + arr2[i])
}
```

Assuming arr1 and arr2 have the same length.